# Alt+<Key> shortcut for combobox opening

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

Let's assume that we have the following XAML:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

        <Button Content="_Test" Margin="12" Width="200" Height="30" Click="OnClick" />

        <ComboBox Margin="12" Width="200" Height="30" >
            <ComboBox.Items>
                <ComboBoxItem>First</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Second</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Third</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox.Items>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Alt+T shortcut will press the button. How can I make Alt+R shortcut opening the combobox dropdown?

**Update:** BTW, I'm aware about Label's Target property and I know that I can create KeyBinding (or something similar) and handle for example Ctrl+R, but I'm looking for more simple way.

Comment: How can I do the same using keyBinding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution. Not so simple as I expected, but I can live with it.

First, I need to specify the name of the ComboBox:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="ResourcesComboBox" Margin="12" Width="200" Height="30" >
        <ComboBox.Items>
            <ComboBoxItem>First</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Second</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Third</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox.Items>
    </ComboBox>
```

Second, register in the view constructor the access key 'R' and open ComboBox in the event handler:

```
    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AccessKeyManager.Register("R", ResourcesComboBox);
        AccessKeyManager.AddAccessKeyPressedHandler(ResourcesComboBox, AccessKeyPressedEventHandler);
    }

    //...

    private void AccessKeyPressedEventHandler(object sender, AccessKeyPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        ResourcesComboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    }
```